# Python: Split list into list of lists

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose that I have list:

```
list = [(4, 7), (3, 7), (5, 7), (4, 6), (4, 8), (2, 7), (3, 6), (3, 8), (6, 7)]
```

That I want to divide the list into sublists of lengths: `[2, 3, 4]` (these lengths can vary)

To produce: `sublist_list = [[(4, 7), (3, 7)],[(5, 7), (4, 6), (4, 8)], [(2, 7), (3, 6), (3, 8), (6, 7)]]`

What's the quickest way that I can do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
myList = [(4, 7), (3, 7), (5, 7), (4, 6), (4, 8), (2, 7), (3, 6), (3, 8), (6, 7)]

listOfLengths = [2, 3, 4]

def getSublists(listOfLengths,myList):
    listOfSublists = []
    for i in range(0,len(listOfLengths)):
        if i == 0:
            listOfSublists.append(myList[:listOfLengths[i]])
        else:
            listOfSublists.append(myList[listOfLengths[i-1]:listOfLengths[i-1]+listOfLengths[i]])
    return listOfSublists
```

Then if you call `getSublists` on your `myList` (original list input) and `listOfLengths` (a list containing the length of your sublists), you get

```
#In: getSublists(listOfLengths,myList)
#Out: [[(4, 7), (3, 7)], [(5, 7), (4, 6), (4, 8)], [(4, 6), (4, 8), (2, 7), (3, 6)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user list[i:j] feature in python which returns a new list contains 
list[i] to list[j-1] elements of original list.

```
base = 0
Lengths =[] #list of lengths
for num in Length:
   sub_list.append(List[base:num+base])
   base += num #jump to next length
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply iterating the list and appending to the new lists?

```
c = 0
for sublist in list:
    sublistlist[len(sublistlist)-1].append(sublist)
    c += 1
    if c % 2:
        sublistlist.append([])
```